# How do I intrinsically constrain interface member types without providing them explicitly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a generic interface for a table component's schema (see below) and can't seem to figure out how to tell the TypeScript compiler that `renderCell`'s argument type is the same as `dataExtractor`'s return type without explicitly supplying it.

`RowType` is supplied, but I assumed `CellType` could be used solely as a constraint.

Alas, tsc spits out the error `Generic type 'TableColumnType<RowType, CellType>' requires 2 type argument(s).`

Do you guys have any suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

Edit: The CellType should be inferred from the dayaExtractor’s return type.

```js
interface TableColumnType<RowType, CellType> {
  name: string;
  dataExtractor: (row: RowType) => CellType;
  renderCell: (data: CellType) => React.ReactChild;
  sortable?: boolean;
  sortFunction: (row: RowType) => number;
}

interface TableSchemaType<T> {
  columns: TableColumnType<T>[];
}
```

*I swear I've done this before this exact way*

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says: `TableSchemaType` requires 2 type arguments. For `RowType` and `CellType`. Your `TableSchemaType` only has one argument.

Your could do something like this:

```js
interface TableSchemaType<T, U> {
  columns: TableColumnType<T, U>[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’m afraid my question might not have been clear enough. In my case I want the CellType to be variable between different rows in the schema. So what I want the TS compiler to understand is that whatever type the dataExtractor returns, the renderCell method should take as an argument. I know this is possible, I’m just stumped as to how the generic syntax should look.